# Combination and Permutation

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics, sets

How could I obtain the list of all the groups of 5 numbers taken from `Range[12]` such that the 2 lists have an empty intersection :

`{{1,2,3,4,5},{6,7,8,9,10}}` would be a solution while

`{{1,2,3,4,5}, {5,6,7,8,9}}` should be rejected as 5 is common to both.

I am currently trying to do so using `Position` of empty `Intersection` very unsuccessfully.

```
allCombinations = 
 DeleteDuplicates@(Sort /@ Permutations[Range[12], {5}])

Function[base,
  Flatten[
   Position[
    Intersection[allCombinations[[base]], allCombinations[[#]]] & /@ 
     Drop[Range[792], {base}], {}], 1]] /@ Range[792]
```

With which I am trying to obtain the position of the lists in allCombination
s, but I still get duplicates...

Comment: I'm assuming you want all possible _pairs_ of lists, right?

Comment: `Subsets[Range[12], {5}]` has 792 elements. Pairing up results in a further combinatorial explosion. Some cleverness will be necessary.

Comment: Is the question general, i.e. how to get all non-intersecting size-$n$ subsets of a size-$m$ set?  (This would cover all non-intersecting 3-element subsets of a 25 element set as well.) Or do you only need to partition sets into two parts (but not more than two)?

Comment: @Szabolcs, both ! My present problem was your second argument, but it is great to learn from solutions how to extend it :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take all subsets of length 10, then for each one find all splits into two sets of five such that the first of the ten is in the first part of the split.

```
In[29]:= Timing[
 msets = Subsets[Range[12], {10}];
 m2 = Flatten[
   Map[With[{fst = First[#], subs = Subsets[Rest[#], {4}], mset = #}, 
      With[{s2 = Map[Join[{fst}, #] &, subs]}, 
       Map[{#, Complement[mset, #]} &, s2]]] &, msets], 1];]

Out[29]= {0.07799999999999985, Null}

In[30]:= Length[m2]

Out[30]= 8316
```

Answer (score 7):

This should be fast enough:

```
 Flatten[
     Map[
       Transpose[{ConstantArray[#1,{Length[#2]}],#2}]&@@
          {#,Subsets[Complement[Range[12],#],{5}]}&,
       Subsets[Range[12],{5}]
     ],
     1]//Short//Timing

(*
   ==>  {0.031,{{{1,2,3,4,5},{6,7,8,9,10}},<<16630>>,{{8,9,10,11,12},{3,4,5,6,7}}}}
*)
```

If you don't want double- counting, apply `Union[Sort/@#]&` to the result - will still be fast.

Comment: @R.M That could be fixed by using `Complement[Range[12], #, Range[Min[#]]]`.

Comment: @R.M. I added a note on that, while you were writing the comment - the overhead of avoiding duplicates is not very large. The biggest win is to avoid blind search over millions of combinations - post-processing a relatively small list of results is not a big deal.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, you could make it right with the duplicates and faster by asking only for half of the subsets, Subsets[Range[12], {5}, Binomial[12, 5]/2]

Comment: @Rojo Thanks, that's a good point.

Comment: @Leonid, fast indeed ! Thank You !

Comment: I hadn't looked at the question until recently, and I find it funny that this is essentially what I would have done.

Comment: @rcollyer All roads lead to Rome?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Pretty much.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a straightforward solution using `Outer` to get you started. It takes 3 seconds on my machine.

```
Outer[If[OrderedQ[{#1, #2}] && Intersection[#1, #2] == {}, {#1, #2}, ## &[]] &, 
    #, #, 1] &@Subsets[Range@12, {5}]~Flatten~1
```

[image]

Comment: +1.  If we add `// Flatten[#, 1]&` to the end, then a list of pairs is returned.  Also, if the OP does not care about the order within each pair, then the extra condition `OrderedQ[{#1, #2}]` will eliminate equivalent solutions.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps

```
res = With[{list = Range[12]},
    Function[{candidates}, DeleteDuplicates[
       Sort /@ ({#, Complement[candidates, #]} & /@ 
          Subsets[candidates, {5}])]] /@
     (Complement[list, #] & /@ Subsets[list, {2}])
    ]~Flatten~1;

In[42]:= Length[res]

Out[42]= 8316
```

Takes 0.06 secs
Finds 8316 solutions.
I first built all the subsets of 10 numbers out of Range[12].
Then, for each subset of 10 numbers, you find all the 5 subsets and their complements.
Number of subsets of 10 numbers out of 12 is

```
In[44]:= Binomial[12, 10]

Out[44]= 66
```

Now, all the subsets of 5 out of 10

```
In[51]:= Binomial[10, 5]

Out[51]= 252
```

You get

```
In[52]:= % %%

Out[52]= 16632
```

Now, those are counting double. The pair `{{1,2,3,5,7}, {4,6,9,10,11}}` as well as the pair `{{4,6,9,10,11} ,{1,2,3,5,7}}` would be found. So I just flatten and delete half of them. Perhaps there's a way to avoid this but it seemed good enough at first.

```
In[53]:= %/2

Out[53]= 8316
```

Answer (score 5):

Or maybe something like

```
lst = ReplaceList[Subsets[Range[12], {5}], {___, a_, ___, b_, ___} /; 
  Intersection[a, b] === {} :> {a, b}]
```

Slightly different approach would be

```
Flatten[{Position[#, 1], Position[#, 2]} & /@ 
  Permutations[
    Join[ConstantArray[1, 5], ConstantArray[2, 5], ConstantArray[0, 2]]], 
 {{1}, {2}, {4, 3}}]
```

It's a lot faster than the first approach but has the disadvantage that every pair appears twice.

Comment: I like the idea behind you second solution (I came up with the same independently).  My version looks like: `{Pick[Range[12], #, 1], Pick[Range[12], #, 2]} & /@ 
 Permutations[{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3}]`  (just a concept to illustrate, not yet generalized to arbitrary-length sets).  `Union` will easily get rid of duplicates.  *+1*

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks, I tried `Pick` first but it was a factor 8 slower than this version. Plus it gave me a chance to use the fancy form of `Flatten` ;-)

Comment: @Heike, Thank you, I don`t get the mechanism by which you remove duplicates, could you explain ?

Comment: @500 Which mechanism are you referring to? Neither of my solutions uses a mechanism to remove duplicates.

Comment: The First one (pairs only appear once) which i believe other solution don`t do ?

Comment: @500 What the replacement rule `{___, a_, ___, b_, ___} /; Intersection[a, b] === {} :> {a_, b_}` does is replacing the whole list of subsets of length 5 with a pair of subsets `{a, b}` for which the intersection is `{}` and for which `a` appears before `b` in the whole list. Since `a` always appears before `b` in the list, no duplicates are ever produced.

Answer (score 3):

The idea is generating all subsets of length $s$. For each of these sets, the complement with respect to the whole list is calculated, then the subsets of the complement lists, and then each of the original sublists has to be combined with the complement lists.

```
n = 4;
s = 2;
groupings[range_, subrange_] := Module[{rest, subsets, result, list},

    (* Generate all subsets of length s *)

    list = Subsets[Range[n], {s}];

    (* Find the complement of each subset w.r.t. the whole thing *)

    rest = Complement[Range[range], #] & /@ list;

    (* Generate possible subsets of that complement *)

    subsets = Subsets[#, {subrange}] & /@ rest;

    (* Everything's been generated now,
    all that's left is data aggregation magic. *)

    result = {list, subsets} // Transpose;
    result = (llist \[Function] {llist[[1]], #} & /@ llist[[2]]) /@
    result;
    result = Flatten[result, 1];
    result = Sort[#, #1[[1]] < #2[[1]] &] & /@ result;
    Union[result]
]
groupings[n, s]
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, {{1, 2, 4}, {3, 5, 6}}, {{1, 2, 5}, {3, 4, 6}}, {{1, 2, 6}, {3, 4, 5}}, {{1, 3, 4}, {2, 5, 6}}, {{1, 3, 5}, {2, 4, 6}}, {{1, 3, 6}, {2, 4, 5}}, {{1, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 6}}, {{1, 4, 6}, {2, 3, 5}}, {{1, 5, 6}, {2, 3, 4}}}
> ```

For $n=12$, $s=5$, this produces $8316$ pairings and takes $0.1$ seconds.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be about 40X faster than Daniel's method and 16X faster than Leonid's.

It works by calculating the sequence of parts for sets of `2 n` (ten in the example) only once, and then extracting those parts from each subset of `set` (`Range[12]` in the example).

```
splits[set_List, n_Integer] :=
  Fold[Partition,
      Join @@ Developer`ToPackedArray[Subsets[set, {2 n}]][[All, #]],
      {n, 2}
  ] & @ Flatten[{#, Range[2 n] ~Complement~ #} & /@ Subsets[Range[2 n - 1], {n}], 2]
```

Usage:

```
splits[Range@12, 5]
```

A minor speed improvement may be had by also packing the parts list, but it does not seem worth the extra code.

Comment: Good idea. I had toyed with doing it once and then using replacement rules but discarded that as likely to be hopelessly slow. But using the "basic case" for parts is very nice (even if it sounds cannibalistic when worded that way).

Comment: @Daniel thank you.  Please see my update for another nice performance boost.  Of course this is only faster if `set` is packable.

Comment: OK, I'll look. (Can't do anything more than that, I already gave you an upvote.)

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for the vote; I wanted your eyes because (1) I thought this was of interest (2) I often make mistakes and I hoped you'd catch any.