# How to partition a list in a specific way

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list:

```
a = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 7, 8}};
```

Using `Partition` and `Map` I get:

```
Partition[#, 4]& /@ a
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}, {{5, 6, 7, 8}, {5, 6, 7, 8}}}
> ```

And now, I would like to get a list which looks like:

```
 {{{{1, 2},{3, 4}}, {{1, 2},{3, 4}}}, {{{5, 6},{7, 8}}, {{5, 6},{7, 8}}}}
```

I tried to play around with `Partition` and `Map`, but I did not manage to create such a list. Of course there are easy ways to do it using `Do` loops and `AppendTo`, but I very much need to avoid `Do` loops. Does anybody see the way to create the list?

Comment: Related: [(13147)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13147/121)

Comment: Oh, look, a binary tree!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a new function in *Mathematica 9* - [`ArrayReshape`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ArrayReshape.html):

```
ArrayReshape[a, {2, 2, 2, 2}]
```

> ```
> {{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}}, {{{5, 6}, {7, 8}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}}}
> ```

Comment: I am copying from the help... A function based on Partition equivalent to `ArrayReshape` without padding: `pareshape[list_, dims_] := 
 Fold[Partition, Flatten[list], dims[[-1 ;; 2 ;; -1]]]`

Answer (score 11):

If you don't have Mathematica 9, this does the same thing as ArrayReshape as shown by Artes.

```
InverseFlatten[l_,dimensions_]:=Fold[Partition,Flatten@l,Most[Reverse[dimensions]]];
a = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 7, 8}};
InverseFlatten[a, {2, 2, 2, 2}]
```

> ```
> {{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}}, {{{5, 6}, {7, 8}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}}}
> ```

Comment: +1. I have been using exactly this code in a number of cases where I needed this functionality.

Comment: Very nice (+1), but no need for `Partition[#1,#2]&` when merely `Partition` will do.

Comment: True I'll change this. Credit to Michael Pilat for this code http://stackoverflow.com/a/3808284/884752

Comment: @Leonid yes this can be useful to write code that works independently of the dimension of a list (so on a flattened list), and then using such function before the part of the code that needs the input to have a given dimension.

Comment: Edited at the source.  Even the best make that mistake it seems.

Answer (score 9):

Artes' approach looks great. Here's another possibility:

```
Nest[Partition[#, 2] &, #, 2] & /@ a
```

> {{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}}, {{{5, 6}, {7, 8}}, {{5, 6}, {7,
>        8}}}}

Answer (score 8):

A general recursive formula:

```
a = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 7, 8}};

f[x_Integer | {x_}] := x;
f[x_List] := f /@ Partition[x, Length@x/2];

f /@ a
```

> ```
>   {{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}}, {{{5, 6}, {7, 8}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}}}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

This isn't as much showing you a good way to achieve your goal as it is to show how `Map` can be applied to parts of a list at different levels (since you said you weren't able to get `Map` and `Partition` to do what you wanted):

So continuing from your step:

```
aa = Partition[#, 4] & /@ a
```

which is shorthand for `Map[Partition[#, 4] &, a]` which is equivalent to 
`Map[Partition[#, 4] &, a, {1}]`, where the `{1}` is the *level specification* of where you want `Map`to act.

If you now did:

```
aaa = Map[Partition[#, 2] &, aa, {2}]
```

you would get your desired result.

Again, Artes and others have shown betters ways of doing your task, but I thought this was a good place to mention this option in `Map`. For more info, take a look at the documentation for `Map`, which (on *Mathematica* 9, at least) also has a link to the tutorial *"Applying Functions to Parts of Expressions"*.

Answer (score 4):

Late to the party and drawing on other answers, but I rather like this:

```
Fold[Partition, #, {2, 2}] & /@ a
```

This is essentially the same as Faysal's answer but specific to this question.  It is also very similar to what I proposed for [Reshape vectors exactly like in MATLAB](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13147/reshape-vectors-exactly-like-in-matlab/13189#13189) and not unlike my code for [Combination and Permutation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/950/combination-and-permutation/1071#1071) so I feel justified in posting it.

Answer (score 3):

```
Partition[#, 2] &  /@ (Partition[#, 2] & /@ a)
```

> {{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}}, {{{5, 6}, {7, 8}}, {{5, 6}, {7,
>        8}}}}

Answer (score 2):

```
Partition[#, 4, 4, None, {}, Partition[{##}, 2] &] & /@ a
```

> {{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}},
>         {{{5, 6}, {7, 8}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}}}