# Merge two lists for List3DPlot

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a two lists:
`list1 = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}, {x4, y4}, {x5, y5}}` and `list2 = {z1, z2, z3, z4, z5}` and I want to make a third one like this `output = {{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}, {x3, y3, z3}, {x4, y4,z4}, {x5, y5, z5}}`
What nice command can do the trick? It is to do a `ListPlot3D` with two lists with more than 10000 entries.
I tried with `Map` and pure function but it is giving me troubles.
Thank you

Comment: You want to add a column to the existing matrix. Try to look for such statement in old posts here.

Comment: `MapThread[Append, {list1, list2}]`

Comment: I recommend taking a look at `ArrayReshape`, see e.g. this question [How to partition a list in a specific way?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38530/how-to-partition-a-list-in-a-specific-way)

Comment: [What is the most effective way to add rows and columns to a matrix](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/189/5467)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Transpose@{list1[[All,1]],list1[[All,2]],list2}
```

or this

```
MapThread[{#1[[1]], #1[[2]], #2} &, {list1, list2}]
```

Comment: Thanks, I will use the MapThread, it is nice!

Answer (score 3):

```
Transpose[Join @@ {Transpose@list1, {list2}}]
```

or

```
Join @@@ Transpose[{list1, List /@ list2}]
```

or

```
Transpose[{Sequence @@ Transpose@list1, list2}]
```

or

```
ArrayReshape[{list1, list2}, Dimensions[list1] + {0, 1}]

(* {{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2},{x3,y3,z3},{x4,y4,z4},{x5,y5,z5}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

With the last parameter of `Join`:

```
Join[list1, List /@ list2, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Flatten /@ MapThread[List, {list1, list2}]
```

or

```
MapThread[Append, {list1, list2}]
```

or

```
Thread[f[list1, list2]] /. f -> Append
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another one, with `MapIndexed`

```
 MapIndexed[ {list1[[Last@#2,1]],list1[[Last@#2,2]],#1},list2]
```