# Partition a range of integers into triples

Tags: combinatorics, partitions

Some time ago, I was asked to look at a simple to formulate puzzle. Consider the list of numbers `{1,2, ..., 33}`. Try to split this list in 11 triples, such that in every triple the third number is the sum of the two others. Obviously, this puzzle can be generalized: let nn be a multiple of 3, then try to split the list `{1,2, ..., nn}` into triples, such that in every triple the largest number is the sum of the two others.

Since it is not immediately clear, at least to me, how to do that with pen and paper, I wrote a Mathematica program for solving this problem with backtracking, see my answer below. To my surprise, when there is not a bug in my program, the results suggest that such a splitting is impossible. Of course I did this testing only for small multiples of 3, up to 48. Otherwise, the backtracking takes far too much time. Maybe there are better techniques. Anyway, I could prove that for odd multiples of 3 the splitting indeed is impossible. Would that be true for even multiples as well?

**EDIT**

Clearly, the answer of @ubpdqn shows that I must have been terrible incorrect, both in my "proof" that for odd multiples of 3 the splitting is impossible, and in my backtracking program, that did not find any partition at all. I updated my answer.

Comment: Where's your "answer below"?

Comment: @David I still was typing it ... Now it is there.

Comment: related : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71827/partitioning-with-constraints-on-subsets/71900#comment197084_71900

Answer (score 6):

We may assume that the partition we are looking for is ordered, and that every triple is ordered as well. When we flatten this list of partitions, we arrive at a permutation of the first nn integers, such that the first value is 1, the values at the positions 1,4,7, ... are increasing, and for every n the values at the positions 3n+1, 3n+2 and 3n+3 are increasing and the value at position 3n+3 is the sum of the values at the positions 3n+1 and 3n+2. Moreover, each value at the positions 1,4,7,... must be less than nn/2. Our backtracking process tries to construct this list, in the implementation called **result**. At any stage we have a number k, the position at which we have to place a number in the list **result**, and moreover a list called **available** of the numbers from which we can choose. We start with the list **result** with the first number 1 placed, the list **available** with the complete range and `k=1`. The construction is then as follows:

- when we are at a position with mod(k,3)=1, we place the smallest available numberless than nn/2 and larger than the last placed number at that position. If that is impossible, we go back to position 2 at the previous triple.
- when we are at a position with mod(k,3)=2, we complete the triple with the smallest available second value. If that is impossible, we go back to position 1 of the same triple.

Here is the implementation.

```
ggg=Compile[{{nn,_Integer, 0}},
  Module[{result, available, k, a,b,c,n},
   result=Table[0,{nn}];
   result[[1]]=1;
   available=Range[nn];
   available[[1]]=0;
   k=2;
   While[2<=k<=nn,
     Which[
       Mod[k,3]==1&&k<nn,
        n=0;Do[If[available[[i]]==i,n=i; Break[]],{i,result[[k]]+1,nn}];
        If[1<=n<nn/2, result[[k]]=n; available[[n]]=0; k=k+1,
          Do[available[[i]]=i, {i, result[[{k-2,k-1}]]}];
          result[[k]]=0;result[[k-1]]=0;k=Max[{k-2, 0}]],
        Mod[k,3]==2&&k<nn,
          a=result[[k-1]];
          b=0;c=0;
          n=result[[k]]; If[n==0, n=a];
          Do[If[available[[i]]==i, c=a+i; Which[c>nn, Break[],
            available[[c]]==c, b=i;Break[]]], {i,n+1,nn}];
          If[b>0,
            result[[k]]=b; result[[k+1]]=c; k=k+2; available[[b]]=0;available[[c]]=0,
            result[[k]]=0; available[[a]]=a;k=k-1] 
         ]];
    result], CompilationTarget->"C"];

Partition[ggg[27], 3] // Timing
(* {13.3693,{{1,2,3},{4,14,18},{5,16,21},{6,19,25},{7,20,27},
  {8,15,23},{9,17,26},{10,12,22},{11,13,24}}} *)
```

The argument of the function ggg must be a multiple of 3. When for such a value a partion does not exist, a list containing zeros is returned.

Now we can try a lot of arguments, but we can restrict the domain. Since every third number is the sum of its two predecessors, the sum of all third numbers must be half of the sum of all numbers, so when the sum of all numbers is odd, such a partition does not exist. Therefore, a necessary condition for a partition to exist is that nn(nn+1)/2 is even, that is nn has to a multiple of 4 or nn+1 has to be a multiple of 4.

That can be seen in a different way as well. In every triple there are 0 or 2 odd numbers. Therefore, in the range of nn there must be an even amount of odd numbers, which means that nn has to be a multiple of 4 or nn+1 has to be a multiple of 4.

We only have to consider the values 3, 12, 15, 24, 27, 36, 39, ...

Already for nn=36, the number of situations that have to be considered is so large that  a partition can hardly be found in a reasonably time. We can reduce the number of situations with another assumption, that seems to be satisfied: there is a partition with the property that the successive triples start with 1, 2, 3, .... That gives the following function:

```
hhh=Compile[{{nn,_Integer,0}},Module[{result, available, k,a,b,c,n},result=Table[0,{nn}];
  Do[result[[3i-2]]=i,{i,1,nn/3}];
  available=Range[nn];
  Do[available[[i]]=0, {i,1,nn/3}];
  k=2;
  While[1<k<nn,
    a=result[[k-1]];
    b=0;c=0;
    n=result[[k]]; If[n==0, n=a];
    Do[If[available[[i]]==i, c=a+i; Which[c>nn, Break[], available[[c]]==c, b=i;Break[]]],
      {i,n+1,nn}];
     If[b>0,
      result[[k]]=b; result[[k+1]]=c; k=k+3; available[[b]]=0; available[[c]]=0,
      available[[result[[k-3]]]]=result[[k-3]];available[[result[[k-2]]]]=result[[k-2]];
      result[[k-2]]=0; result[[k]]=0; k=k-3] ];
  result],
  CompilationTarget->"C"];
```

This is considerably faster:

```
Partition[hhh[27],3]//Timing

(* {0.,{{1,10,11},{2,12,14},{3,15,18},{4,19,23},{5,22,27},{6,20,26},
```

{7,17,24},{8,13,21},{9,16,25}}} *)

We now can go even as far as 60:

```
Partition[hhh[60],3]//Timing

(* {42.2451,{{1,21,22},{2,23,25},{3,24,27},{4,26,30},{5,28,33},{6,29,35},
{7,34,41},{8,40,48},{9,42,51},{10,39,49},{11,45,56},{12,46,58},{13,47,60},
{14,43,57},{15,44,59},{16,37,53},{17,38,55},{18,36,54},{19,31,50},20,32,52}}} *)
```

These results strongly suggest that the condition that nn or nn+1 is a multiple of 4 is also sufficient.

Comment: Nice, analysis, +1

Comment: @FredSimons,,,I have looked (inefficiently) at `Range[9,27,3]`, stopping due to explosion and have found partitions for 12, 15, 24, and 27. See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/80371/1997

Answer (score 4):

My original answer fortuitously found the some near complete partitions. But I post this edited answer...illustrating the combinatorial explosion exploring cases `Range[9,27,3]`:

```
f[n_] := Module[{su, p, pc, u, grp},
  su = Subsets[Range[n], {3}];
  p = Pick[su, #.{1, 1, -1} == 0 & /@ su];
  pc = Subsets[p, {2}];
  u = Pick[pc, Length /@ (Intersection @@@ pc), 0];
  grp = Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ u];
  {n, Length@FindClique[grp, {n/3}, All], 
   HighlightGraph[grp, 
    Subgraph[grp, FindClique[grp], GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick"]], 
   FindClique[grp, {n/3}]}]
```

Tabulating results:

```
res = f[#] & /@ Range[9, 27, 3];
resp = Prepend[
   res, {"n", "Number of partitions", "Graph and largest clique", 
    "Example Partition"}];
Grid[resp, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

A heuristic (but incomplete: compare with above) is to just use `FindClique` which tries to fiind largest clique.

```
h[n_] := Module[{su, p, pc, u, grp},
  su = Subsets[Range[n], {3}];
  p = Pick[su, #.{1, 1, -1} == 0 & /@ su];
  pc = Subsets[p, {2}];
  u = Pick[pc, Length /@ (Intersection @@@ pc), 0];
  grp = Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ u];
  {n, Sequence @@ ({#[[1]], Length @@ #} &@FindClique[grp, n/3])}]
style[{a_, b_, c_}] := 
 If[a/3 == c, Style[#, Red] & /@ {a, b, c}, {a, b, c}]
```

Looking at `Range[9,60,3]`:

```
Grid[style /@ (h /@ Range[9, 60, 3])]
```

36, 51 and 60 clearly have partitions but is uncertain wrt others (see above, e.g. 12, 24, 27}:

[image]

Comment: This is really wonderful! I do not know anything about graph theory (maybe you could very shortly explain the idea behind your solution), but your results show that I must have made at least two errors. One in my proof that for odd nn such partitions do not exist (I found that error, and feel ashamed) and one in my backtracking program that did not find these partitions. That takes more time to find out, but in the very near future I hope to be able to repair it. Many thanks for looking at this problem and congratulations with the result!

Comment: @FredSimons thank you for kind words. I make too many mistakes to mention but the most embarrassing ones are also the greatest opportunities, even if mixed with shame...had a lot of shame. I enjoyed thinking about the puzzle and doubtless you and others could find better ways but re looking at small n was useful for me. I am not near computer at present but when time permits will explain approach a bit clearer.

Comment: @FredSimons basically I generate the triples that have the property t1+t2=t3. Next I select from the pairs of triples those that have no common member and make a graph where node/vertex is triple and edge is pair of triples that are disjoint.  Originally I tried to build chains but using `FindClique` finds all mutually disjoint triples (complete subgraph). If there is clique of size n/3 it is a set of mutually disjoint triples that span the range-> a solution.